# I am getting errors in IntelliJ when adding MVN dependency- Selenium Java » 3.141.59. Any suggestions?

Tags: selenium

I am getting below errors:
Dependency 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.141.59' not found
Dependency 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.141.59' not found
Dependency 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.141.59' not found[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNNuZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Once any changes are made in `pom.xml` you must refresh it by clicking on following button (see screenshot).
It will trigger Maven to refresh and download needed dependencies/plugins according to `pom.xml` file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please **reload** the **pom.xml** by mentioned in the picture.

> right click -> maven -> Reload Project

[image]